# i want access value in another function in the node is but I am getting result undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to acccess rate out side any variable

```
        rates.fromBTC(1, currency, function (err, rate) {     
                return rate;
        })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It would help if you included more context to your question.

Comment: This is like an asynchronous operation.  As such, you cannot return the result and use it outside the callback.  Instead, you must use the result inside the callback or in some function you call from within that callback and pass the value to.  This is how asynchronous development works in node.js.  See the question yours has been marked a duplicate of for a very detailed description of this issue.  This is one of the most common duplicate questions related to node.js as everyone starting with node.js has to go through a learning curve to learn how to write async code.

Answer (score -1):

```
var rates = require('./rate.js');

rates.fromBTC(1, currency, function (response) {     
        console.log(response) //you will get rate here
})

//in rate.js file
exports.fromBTC = function(num,currency,callback){
  /*
  do some operation to find rate
  */
  return callback
}
```

Comment: This is one of the most common duplicate questions asked related to node.js so we don't need yet another answer.  Plus your answer does not seem to explain or solve the problem either.

Comment: thanks sir but i am new in  node js and i want 'rates' for all 'currency' and send response only one ' list' . i have trying and error are occur  Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client . please give me suggestion what am i do ?

Comment: app.post('/',function(req,res)
 {
  var  currency;
     currency= ["INR","USD"];
    currency.forEach(function(value) {
  
       console.log("currency : "+value);
       rates.fromBTC(1, value,function (err, rate)
       { 
    console.log("getting value for "+ value +" and value is : "+ rate)

    res.send("currency rates "+rate);
       });// value+"value is a "
     });
 }); 
app.listen(3003);
console.log("3000 port is running a my app");

Comment: what is meaning of

Comment: this question is marked as duplicate by some one.please refer that question.